# How to filter a grid view with a RadioBUttonList and Where Clausole

Tags: c#, asp.net, entitydatasource

I use C# in ASP.NET 4.

I have a GridView and an EntityDataSource for binding it with the DataBase.

**Source DB Table contains a Bool Column** (0,1).

I would like to filter the result in the GridView using a RadioList button or similar.

Adding the WhereParameters to the Entity Set I get an error:

```
String was not recognized as a valid Boolean.
```

### Any idea how to solve it? Thanks

```
    <WhereParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="uxFilterMessageTypeSelector" 
            Name="TypeMessage" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="uxFilterIsReplied" Name="IsReplied" 
            PropertyName="SelectedValue" DbType="Boolean" />
    </WhereParameters>
```

---

```
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="uxFilterIsReplied" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
        <asp:ListItem Value="Y">1</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="F">0</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your RadioButtonList to the following:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="uxFilterIsReplied" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
    <asp:ListItem Value="True">1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="False">0</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Then the String will be a recognized Boolean value.